# decide the point is in which section of rectangle

Tags: algorithm

I have a rectangle which has known width and height.Now devide rectangle diagonally to form four triangles. Now suppose have a point p(m,n) and i have to decide that the point lies in which triangle out of four triangles.
Please suggest me some good algo.

Comment: There is this new thing called Google. All the cool kids are doing it.

Comment: If the rectangle has only "width and height", but no specific position on the plane, then the problem makes no sense. Firstly, you have to specify the position of the rectangle. Secondly, you have to specify what orientations of the rectangle are allowed. Is it axis-parallel or not? What is `m` and `n` - coordinates on the plane? Or coordinates inside the rectangle?

Comment: we have a rectangle in x-y plane also the point m,n are arbitary point and we have to decide whether it lies in the rectangle..i mean in which section?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting question. I think this algorithm should do it, but I haven't tried it out yet. Assuming that the rectangle is AxB and the point p(m,n).

```
int section = (m * B < n * A) * 2 + (m > A / 2 || n > B / 2);
```

The variable section should then be a value between 0 and 3, depending where the point resides. The sections are called:

```
  0  
2   1
  3
```

If you wish to name the sections another way feel free to tweak the algo.

Comment: The sign < or > stands for what?

Comment: Less than and greater than. If the statement inside the parenthesis is true, then the value is 1, otherwise 0. The double vertical bars means that one of the two statements must be true.

Answer (score 4):

Well you know the line equations of the diagonals(because you have two points). Both of the diagonals define two halfplanes.

Diagonal1 equation:

```
A1 * x + B1 * y + C1 = 0
```

Diagonal2 equation:

```
A2 * x + B2 * y + C2 = 0
```

It becomes:

Substitute `A1 * m + B1 * n + C1` to find in which halfplane is the point for the first diagonal. If the number is `< 0`, then it lies in one halfplane, if it is `> 0` then it lies in the other.

Substitute `A2 * m + B2 * n + C2` to find in which halfplane is the point for the second diagonal. If the number is `< 0`, then it lies in one halfplane, if it is `> 0` then it lies in the other.

Comment: But we have 4 triangle...we have to find out above to diag1 and below to diag2..something like this type

Answer (score 0):

if((x * height < y * width) || ( x*width < y*height ))
                    {
                        test = 1;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        test = 0;
                    }
                    if((x > width / 2 && y > height / 2))
                    {
                        test1=1;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        test1=0;
                    }
                    int section = (test) * 2 + (test1);

```
                switch(section)
                {
                case 0:
                    Log.d("ABSAR","UP button");

                    break;
                case 1:
                    Log.d("ABSAR","RIGHT button");

                    break;
                case 2:
                    Log.d("ABSAR","LEFT button");

                    break;
                case 3:
                    Log.d("ABSAR","DOWN button");

                    break;
                }
```

`if point P(x,y) and the rectangle of dimension width * height
Then above code works OK...